# How to store PDF, ZIP and other files using ArangoDB?

Tags: database, arangodb

I would like to store PDF, ZIP and other types of files. What is the best way to do it in ArangoDB?

Answer (score 2):

While ArangoDB would be able to store raw binary data such as PDF and ZIP since the introduction of [VelocyPack](https://github.com/arangodb/velocypack) as internal storage format in v3.0, it is [unclear how to support this over JSON](https://github.com/arangodb/arangodb/issues/107).

It's possible to represent the binary data in base64 and store it like text, but encoding / decoding would need to be handled by the client. I highly discourage you from doing so because it potentially creates giant documents, which harms performance especially if such documents are [updated frequently](https://docs.arangodb.com/3.3/Manual/Architecture/#appendonlymvcc).

The recommended way is to store files on the server with Foxx and reference them inside the database by their file paths:

[Blog: Handling Binary Data in Foxx 3.0](http://jsteemann.github.io/blog/2016/06/22/handling-binary-data-in-foxx-3-0/)